# Passing information from a screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm looking to pass the content of a ThreeLineListItem into another screen so I can just use its details to get power readings and display it separately. I have tried to research it but I did not find anything relative to what I'm looking for. Can someone please help? Do I have to pass it as a parameter somehow?

main.py:

```
from kasa.discover import Discover
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarIconListItem, ThreeLineListItem, TwoLineListItem
from decimal import Decimal
from pyemvue import PyEmVue, device
import datetime
import asyncio
from enum import Enum
class Scale(Enum):
    SECOND = '1S'
    MINUTE = '1MIN'
    MINUTES_15 = '15MIN'
    HOUR = '1H'
    DAY = '1D'
    WEEK = '1W'
    MONTH = '1MON'
    YEAR = '1Y'

class Unit(Enum):
    KWH = 'KilowattHours'
    USD = 'Dollars'
    AMPHOURS = 'AmpHours'
    TREES = 'Trees'
    GAS = 'GallonsOfGas'
    DRIVEN = 'MilesDriven'
    CARBON = 'Carbon'

vue = PyEmVue()
vue.login(username='mymalshamsi@gmail.com', password='Moh123123!')

class Page1(Screen):
    mdlistid = ObjectProperty()
    def create_new_item(self,*args):
        plugs = asyncio.run(Discover.discover())
        devices = vue.get_devices()
        usage_over_time, start_time = vue.get_chart_usage(devices[1].channels[0], datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)-datetime.timedelta(minutes=5), datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc), scale=Scale.MINUTE.value, unit=Unit.KWH.value)
        for addr, dev in plugs.items():
            asyncio.run(dev.update())
            item = ThreeLineListItem(text=dev.alias, secondary_text= "Current Reading: {:.2f}".format(dev.emeter_realtime['power'] / 100) + " kW",tertiary_text= "IP Address: " + addr)
            item.bind(on_release=self.change_page)
            self.mdlistid.add_widget(item) 
            item = TwoLineListItem(text= devices[0].device_name, secondary_text= "Current Reading: " + str(usage_over_time[3]) + "kWh")
            item.bind(on_release=self.change_page)
            self.mdlistid.add_widget(item)
    def change_page(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'page2'
class Page2(Screen):
    pass
class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('app.kv')
        return SM()
MainApp().run()
```

app.kv

```
<SM>:
    Page1:
        name: 'page1'
    Page2:
        name: 'page2'
<Page1>:
    mdlistid:mdlistid
    MDBottomNavigation:
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'devices'
            text: 'Devices'
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                Button:
                    size_hint_y:.1
                    text: 'Seek Devices'
                    on_release: root.create_new_item()
                MDList:
                    size_hint_y:.9
                    id: mdlistid
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'predictions'
            text: 'Predictions'
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                MDList:
                    size_hint_y: .9
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: 'Predictions go here!'
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'recommendations'
            text: 'Recommendations'
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                MDList:
                    size_hint_y: .9
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: 'Recommendations go here!'
<Page2>:
    Button:
        text: 'Go Page 1'
        size_hint:None,None
        size: 250,250
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'page1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object on other screens through the id of the widgets in the App. There are two ways that I know can do so.

First you need to give an id to the screens, in you .kv file,

```
<SM>:
    Page1:
        name: 'page1'
        id : page_1
    Page2:
        name: 'page2'
        id : page_2
```

If it is an attribute and you want to pass it to `page 2` you can define a function in `page 2` and call it in `page 1` and pass the argument at the same time, before changing the screen.

So, in `class Page2` add you can add something like

```
def get_reading(reading):
    self.reading = reading
```

Then inside the `change_page` function of `page 1`

```
def change_page(self,*args):
    self.manager.ids.page_2.get_reading(<your_attribute_here>)
    self.manager.current = 'page2'
```

Otherwise, you can also access the object in `page 1` directly from `page 2` by

```
temp = App.get_running_app()
page_1 = temp.root.ids.page_1.<your_object>
```